# OSGI startup is very slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, osgi, startup

I'm trying to figure out why the OSGI startup process of our RCP application is so slow and were the time is lost.

I have enabled osgi.debug with the following options:

> org.eclipse.osgi/profile/startup = true
>   org.eclipse.osgi/profile/benchmark = true
>   org.eclipse.osgi/profile/debug = true

Below is a snippet from the profiling output

> - 9754 :     0       >> BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > enter
> - 9754 :     0       -- BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > calling initial@reference:file:plugins/com.razorcat.ite.ui.views_1.0.0 .jar/
>     bundle activator
> - 9754 :     0       -- BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > returned from initial@reference:file:plugins/com.razorcat.ite.ui.views
>     _1.0.0.jar/ bundle activator
> - 9754 :     0       << BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > exit
> - 38896 : 29142       >> BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > enter
> - 38896 :     0       -- BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > calling initial@reference:file:plugins/com.razorcat.tessy.remoting.web
>     app_1.0.1.jar/ bundle activator
> - 38896 :     0       -- BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > returned from initial@reference:file:plugins/com.razorcat.tessy.remoti
>     ng.webapp_1.0.1.jar/ bundle activator
> - 38896 :     0       << BundleContextImpl.startActivator() > exit

I wonder if there is a way to find were the time (ca. 30 secs) is lost between the exit and enter entry. Is there any option to more fine tune the profiling output?

Comment: Enter the command "jps" and find the pid of your application. After that, enter the command "jstack -l PID" several times so you can check thread dump where the threads are waiting (there will be one longer one, that will be the cause). If you do not find the cause, append the stack to your question. If the thread dump is long, you can run "jstack -l PID >>out.txt"

Comment: Use a java profiler to monitor what is going on in your application at runtime.  There is no way for us to know based on this information.